# tkinter with mac osx

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a very basic question related to Python 3. I have started to learn Python but some things are confusing me.

First off, since I want to create a python script that is a GUI, I have imported the `tkinter` module.  The code works in IDLE, but never works when I run it from the terminal. Whenever I run the script from the terminal, I see this traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    mGui.geometry("geometry 480x480") 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/
__init__.py", line 1607, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "geometry 480x480"
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is create a Python GUI script, save it, and execute it via my terminal whenever I need it.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from tkinter import *



mGui =Tk("")
mGui.geometry("geometry 480x480") 
mGui.title("Leilani spelling test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add the word "geometry" to the argument of the `geometry` method.  Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from tkinter import *

mGui =Tk("")
mGui.geometry("480x480") 
mGui.title("Leilani spelling test")
# You'll want to add this to enter the event loop that causes the window to be shown
mGui.mainloop()
```

Here are some other GUI configurations that you may need in the future (I personally had trouble finding/applying all the information):

```
mGui.overrideredirect(1) # Remove shadow & drag bar. Note: Must be used before wm calls otherwise these will be removed.
mGui.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-topmost", "true") # Always keep window on top of others
mGui.geometry("100x100+500+500") # Set offset from top-left corner of screen as well as size
mGui.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-transparent", "true") # Remove shadow from window
mGui.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-fullscreen", "true") # Fullscreen mode
mGui.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-alpha", "0.9") # Window Opacity 0.0-1.0
```

Comment: @Matt I added a new line to my answer.  It looks like you were missing the call to `mainloop`